Can't write two inputs in to stdin with node
My goal was to use gpg in node with child_process to verify a signature from database without passing the file but with the signature text, but when i try to pass the signature and the content to be verified it gives invalid signature, if i pass only the content to stdin and let the signature being the name of the file it works
Example code:
    //spawn('gpg', ['--verify', 'signature.sig', '-']) solves the problem
    const gpg = spawn('gpg', ['--verify', '-', '-'])

    const signature = `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE----- xxxx -----END PGP SIGNATURE-----`
    const content = 'content'

    gpg.stdin.write(signature)
    gpg.stdin.write(content)
    gpg.stdin.end()

    gpg.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
        console.log(`stdout: ${data}`)
    })

    gpg.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
        console.error(`stderr: ${data}`)
    })

    gpg.on('close', (code) => {
        console.log(`Finished with code ${code}`)
    })

What i've already tried:
gpg.stdin.write(signature + "\n" + content + "\n")
gpg.stdin.write(signature + "\n" + content")
gpg.stdin.write(signature)
gpg.stdin.end(content)

What results:
gpg: BAD signature from xxx
